# Anime clip featuring a glowing girl with blue/purple hair and a man dressed like an astronaut

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime features a person dressed as an astronaut, and a glowing ghost of a giggling girl who floats in the air and has holes in her torso.

The astronaut runs away from the ghost at first, then changes his mind and returns to her.

I'm looking for the source.

Here is the video and some screenshots from the video:

[image]

[image]

Comment: To the close voters, what other details would we need? "Here is a thing. Look at the thing. Where is the thing from?" That should be sufficient.

Comment: @SQB Arguably, if the video were to disappear, there would be nothing left from the question, if no screenshot was taken beforehand. That being said, it's still far from needing more details indeed.

Answer (score 15):

The clip comes from the short [Home](https://youtu.be/H4wXUaPGZeg?si=os9L05qt3a56bYwx), with the clip starting at about 2:49 in the original version.

[image]

This is from the Japanese animation company [Orange - cg](https://www.orange-cg.com/)